# JSF 2 error handling doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to do a simple forwarding to an error page in a JSF 2 application. The instructions everywhere seem simple enough but it just doesn't work for me. This is what I tried. I put the following in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
     <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
     <location>/pages/error.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

I tried an exception-type java.lang.Exception, and I tried using error-code instead of the exception-type. I also tried to name the page (in the above snippet) error.xhtml, and I tried all this with an error.jsp page. Nothing works.

I'm testing this by simply disconnecting the database server so any attempt to log in causes an exception. And it's being displayed on the screen instead of the error page.

I'm using eclipse, tomcat 7, and myfaces 2.1.4. Also in my WEB-INF/lib I have primefaces-3.0.RC2 and prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.2.

What am I doing wrong / not doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you shut down the error mechanisms of Facelets? In you web.xml file, you may need to have the following context-param:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you also use MyFaces, you need this additional context-param:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This [article](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-Error.Handling.htm) may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, Mr.J4ams. This works for the view expired exception. I'm still working on the Ajax solution BalusC is proposing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use any managed bean to process the error? If so, have you declared them? Check out this [article](http://blogs.i2m.dk/allan/2008/04/18/creating-a-generic-error-page-for-jsf/).